# Looping through dictionary to find value

Tags: swift

Usually I just step into the dictionary and find the value once inside.  In this case, I need to step in, loop through to find a value then step back out again then find a different value. Example:

```
address_components": [
{
    "long_name": "E3 2AA",
    "short_name": "E3 2AA",
    "types": [
        "postal_code"
    ]
},
{
    "long_name": "London",
    "short_name": "London",
    "types": [
        "postal_town"
    ]
}
]
```

This is what googles api dictionary looks like and I need to fetch the `long_name` of the `postal_town`.

Comment: The value for `address_components` is an array (indicated by the square brackets).

Comment: @vadian Yeah sorry forgot to mention.  Still, trying to fetch the value is I need is still an issue (postal town is not always an index value of 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `first(where:` function passing a closure to filter for the `type`, this avoids a loop:

```
if let addressComponents = json["address_components"] as? [[String:Any]],
    let postalTownComponent = addressComponents.first(where: { ($0["types"] as! [String]).contains("postal_town")  }) {
    print(postalTownComponent["long_name"])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you:

```
let result = addressComponents.filter({ return ($0["types"] as! [String]).contains("postal_town") }).map({ $0["long_name"] })
```

Answer (score 0):

`address_components` is an array so you can just loop over it and check the value of your key. Maybe something like:

```
var names = []

for entry in addressComponent {
    if addressComponent["types"][0] == "postal_town" {
        names.append(addressComponent["long_name"])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it just that simple, or I misunderstand your question? An example:

```
let dict = [ "long_name": "E3 2AA", "short_name": "E3 2AA"]
for (key, value) in dict {
    print("your key: \(key) and value: \(value)")
}
```